# my jQuery code isn't working although there is no error in console

Tags: jquery

Hello guys could you please help with this code I don't know why it's not working

I tried to not shortcut it but it didn't work. Here's my code:

HTML

```
 <div class="testin text-center" >
  <div class="client active">
    <img src="user.jpg" alt=""/>
    <span>client1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="client hidden">
      <img src="user2.png" alt=""/>
      <span>client2</span>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
        //check testimonial
        var rightArrow  = $('.testin .fa-chevron-right'),
                leftArrow = $('.testin .fa-chevron-left');

        function checkClients() {
            $('.client:first').hasClass('active')? rightArrow.fadeOut() : rightArrow.fadeIn();
            $('.client:last').hasClass('active') ? leftArrow.fadeOut() : leftArrow.fadeIn();
        }
        checkClients();
```

I expect to hide the arrow on the right and show the next client
Thank you

Comment: Do those elements exist at the time you define `rightArrow  ` and `leftArrow ` ?

Answer (score 0):

`rightArrow` and `leftArrow` don't exist in the DOM yet. you need to `.append()` them or put them in your HTML from the beginning. `fadeIn()` & `fadeOut()` only make objects visible / hide them.

[jquery append docs](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Making a big assumption that isn't evident in question

Comment: My answer and solution are built on the provided html and jQuery. i did not assume, i used what was shown.

Comment: my mistake , i did put them in HTML but forgot to paste them here anyway it's not working ToT

Comment: @SaraSh In your HTML both chevrons are inside the `.hidden` div. You can not show elements inside a hidden div. If you move them out of there it should work.